# Unable to use Liferay Freindly URL Mapper

Tags: liferay-6

I was following this document from Liferay Website to work Map Firendly URL Mappings

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/adding-friendly-url-mapping-to-the-portlet

I am using   Liferay version=6.1.0

During HyperLink navigation , i was getting the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/what-we-do?p_p_id=sai_WAR_Saiportlet&
p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1
&_sai_WAR_Saiportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fsai%2Fedit.jsp
```

To modify the above i have tried to use Friendly URL Mapper and i have done the following way

Inside liferay-portlet.xml file .

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>sai</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
         <friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper</friendly-url-mapper-class>
         <friendly-url-mapping>sai</friendly-url-mapping>
         <friendly-url-routes>com/test/sai-friendly-url-routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>
        <instanceable>false</instanceable>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>
            /js/main.js
        </footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>sai-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
```

Created a new file by name sai-friendly-url-routes.xml inside

```
D:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT\portlets\Sai-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\src\com\test\sai-friendly-url-routes.xml
```

The content inside sai-friendly-url-routes.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_1_0.dtd">

<routes>
   <route>
      <pattern>/{mvcPathName}</pattern>
      <generated-parameter name="mvcPath">/{mvcPathName}.jsp</generated-parameter>
   </route>
</routes>
```

But i observed there is no change in the url

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/what-we-do?p_p_id=sai_WAR_Saiportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_sai_WAR_Saiportlet_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fsai%2Fedit.jsp
```

Please let me know where exactly i am doing mistake .

Answer (score 1):

You leave the values as they are. That is, you leave {mvcPathName} and "mvcPath" as-is.

When the friendly URL is generated, it parses mvcPath (i.e., edit.jsp or view.jsp) from the URL and then the pattern is applied, replacing .../edit.jsp with .../edit.

This example works for the edit JSP. And it works for the view page; but NOT when clicking Save ... which is something I could look into. However, if you go to edit and then click the back link, the friendly URL will show for the view JSP.

I've created a ticket to complete this example so that it also goes to a friendly URL when clicking save. I'll update this section when we've made the fix.
Thanks.